# Поймать заголовок Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Доброй ночи.

Отправляю ajax запрос к скрипту, а у скрипта стоит переадресация на сайт (допустим example.com). Так вот, как словить, куда хочет перенаправить тебя скрипт, и не получить ошибку типа XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://telegram.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Из браузера — никак, только переделывать сервер, чтобы вместо редиректа отдавал просто ссылку

Comment: @andreymal а разве в ответе не придет статус и адрес куда перенаправляется? типа `$.post('/redirected', {}, function(response, status, request) {
  if (status == STATUS.REDIRECT) {
    console.log(response.redirectUrl);

  }
});`

Comment: всё равно ошибку выводит. мне просто редирект словить нужно :(

Comment: @ikerya а в try/catch обернуть?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский например?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В ответе-то придёт, но браузер никак не позволяет этот ответ прочитать

Answer (score 1):

Что бы не получить ошибку  "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ", сервер должен отдавать этот заголовок.

А получить - ссылку на редирект - программно. Или у тебя нет доступа к серверу?

Comment: Я отправляю запрос с консоля сайта на тот же сайт. Но к этому сайту доступа нету.

Comment: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); Этот заголовок дайте на сторне сервера, и ошибки не будет